# NSMutableArray Meta-Data when exported to CSV file

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, plist, metadata

Looking for some advice with an iOS application.

Essentially what my app does is generate a CSV file that logs certain events within a period of time. So users can press a button and an entry will be added to the log saying "Event of type X happened at Time T"

The way I'm doing this is by maintaining an NSMutableArray which stores NSStrings. Each event adds a string to the NSMutableArray.

When the user is done with a session, they can "export" the file. I'm using the NSMutableArray's writeToFile; then I use an e-mail interface to send that file as a CSV to a target e-mail.

It all works, except the CSV file that is generated has some meta-data in it. Specifically, I believe at the top of the file I see  and  at the beginning of each row of cells when opened in excel.

Is this something inherent in the data structure (NSMutableArray) or data type (NSString) that I am using? Is there a way for me to just get the raw data?

I can upload code if need be (I'm not near the work computer now though, so I'm testing the waters to see if there is something simple I can do to stop seeing this meta-data).

Thank you!

Comment: the writeToFile method will generate a plist file, not a csv file

Comment: Okay, is there any way for me to write it to a csv file? Currently I'm just changing the extension (crude, I know).

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a very simple format. You can separate the strings with semi-colons and then write everything to a file using `NSOutputStream`.

This code assumes you already have a string array with CSV rows:

```
NSOutputStream* csvoutput = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filepath append:NO];
[csvoutput open];
for (NSString* str in array) {
    NSString* tempStr = [str stringByAppendingString:@"\n"]; //new line
    NSData *strData = [tempStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [csvoutput write:(uint8_t *)[strData bytes] maxLength:[strData length]];
}
[csvoutput close];
```

You better create a model class (`Event`) and fill the array with Event-instances instead of strings. Thats cleaner and more efficient. Then you would create the CSV-strings when exporting to a file.